# How to transfer data from potentially dying hard drive?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

I had a fully working HDD as storage (not for the operating system) until I began encountering system crashes due to a defective (new) motherboard.

I have since discovered that my HDD is potentially corrupted. Some data is available, some not.

CHKDSK reveals almost 10K in bad sectors. Previously, everything was working flawlessly. So, I suspect that the crashes may have caused some damage.

I would like to transfer over as much as possible to another hard drive and then format the drive to see if that may actually the solve issue.

The issue is that the hard drive appears to lock up when I try to do this. Is there any alternative software that I could run? I have access to both Linux and Windows 10.

Comment: How large is the HDD ? Have you 2xHDDcapacity free space somewhere else?

Comment: @uDev, the size is 1TB. I am using approximately 200GB.

I have an alternative disk that is 1TB, and has about 500GB that I can partition to adequately hold double the size of the files *stored*, but not the entire size of the drive.

Comment: Ok. I asked because my first step always to create a full image about the defected disk, and work from the image directly. Less point to make mistakes. There's some tools, ex. Runtime GetDataBack which allows to recover files, even if the hard drive has bad sectors. Make sure any software you use it not write back to your dying hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't start your defect disk, if not necessary. Remove it physically from your computer, if possible (until step 3).
2. Get a new drive that is larger than your defective one (same size can be difficult... actual size of new HDDs may vary slighlty due to defect sectors)
3. Reconnect your defective drive to your computer and create a byte-by-byte copy on your new disk. I have made good experience with [ddrescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue), contained in many Linux-Distributions and described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Algorithm).

Be patient, it may take some time (hours, days), depending on drive size, speed (USB, etc,), damage on your disk. For me it took over a week, as I had to run both discs as external drives on my raspberry (USB 2 only...).

In my case, I had only few sectors that could not be recovered by ddrescue. All relevant files were in the good part of the drive,  so I was done here. I just copied the recovered data to a new disk and ditched the old one (ok, for curiosity, I first broke it up to have a look inside it)

(I'll have look tonight for some helpful links -- [that's the one I had in mind](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Examples))

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Okay, so the original disk is 1TB. I have an alternative 1TB, too. I can also virtualise Linux and perform this task. I have a little experience with ddrescue. 

This would mean plugging both in via USB. Would this cause an issue other than transfer speeds?

The actual data used on the 1TB HDD that is defective is approximately 200GB.

Comment: @mpw It would be safest to get a larger disk. Not all 1TB disks have exactly the same amount of space, and you don't want to spin up the faulty HDD just to find out that the alternative 1TB HDD is 1024 bytes smaller. As a bonus, you will then have a 2TB disk for backups.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Would it not be possible to only copy over the files that in use? Or would ddrescue just create a whole copy, bad sectors and all?

Comment: @mpw If I were you, I would read the ddrescue manual that snowflake linked to, at least twice, decide how lucky I felt and if I really cared about getting the data back, then get a new larger disk drive. If the cost of a new HDD is an issue, maybe you know someone with a 2TB disk they can lend you for a couple of weeks on the basis that you will give it back wiped clean.

Comment: @mpw Well, you can try that. If it works, it's likely to be faster than ddrescue and require less space. But if it doesn't, it may do additional harm to your HDD, damage more sectors. If your HDD is really close to dying (as the title of your question suggests), you do not know how often you can start it, each time can be the last time, and you want to rescue as much data as possible. That's what ddrescue is good for. As suggests by Andrew Morton, it always depends on how important the data are for you.

Comment: @mpw if you care about the data don't play with it. Just perform a ddrescue copy as advised.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I wanted to do this but now the disk wont even get recognised. In Windows it wont initialise, in Linux it has input/output errors.

Comment: @mpw ddrescue should skip damaged zones unless 100% of its sectors give IO errors.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to Linux youre dying driver and another, with nte smaller size.

Use:
dr if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=4MB status=progress

Where:
dd - makes copy 1:1, byte by byte one source to another
/dev/sdX - is Your dying drive
/dev/sdY - is Your backup drive (all data willa be lost) or You can write image od sdX as a file. Just use different of - Output File (as on Linux everything is a file). On Linux You can mount then such image and use it as a real physical volume - there is nodifference for Linux 
bs - buffer size. You can use other size.
status - is a way if infirmig You od the precess

You can use aby distro You can download and write it on USB or Burn on CD/DVD. I suggest Mint or Ubuntu as they arę super Simple to use but apparently there willa be no difference because You have to use console / terminal

For detect Your X and Y You can use:
fdisk -l

It might be necesary to become a root user:
sudo su

After dd You can use partitioning program ie. gparted to enlarge copied partition size and stretch it to whole new drive size.